# How to create label in neo4j using nodejs

Tags: node.js, neo4j, label, graph-databases

I used following method to create a node in Neo4j using nodejs. I want to create a node with its label as well as some property.

```
var query = [
        "CREATE (n:TYPE {props})",
        "RETURN n",
    ].join('\n').replace('TYPE','PLAYER'); 
    var params = {
        props: data,
    };


    neo4jClient.query(query, params, function (err, results) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        var node = neo4jClient.createNode(results[0].n._data.data);
        var player = new Player(node);
        node.save(function (err) {
            console.dir(err);
            if (err) return callback(err);            
            node.index(INDEX_NAME, INDEX_KEY, INDEX_VAL, function (err) {               
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback(null, player);
            });
        });
    });
```

Problem :- Everything goes right but this method creates two nodes in neo4j. I don't know what's happening internally. Please give me some input in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You actually execute the query which creates the node (and would be good enough).

But then you go again and create a new node `node.save()` + `node.index()` both of which are not necessary as the `CREATE` query already did the work.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hunger. It works when i remove save and index method. But it persisted in Neo4j database but it is not persisted in nodejs. Means if i create a index on that node then it gives me following error.

Error:- Node must exist before indexing.

Here also they mention to fire save method. 
http://coffeedoc.info/github/thingdom/node-neo4j/master/  (GraphDatabase -> createNode method)

Answer (score 0):

It works with following function.

```
neo4jClient.query(query, params, function (err, results) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        var node = results[0].n;
        var player = new Player(node);  

        node.index(INDEX_NAME, INDEX_KEY, INDEX_VAL, function (err) {               
            if (err) return callback(err);
            console.log("=============================");
            callback(null, player);
        });
    });
```

neo4jClient.query itself create a node so if you call function createNode again then it also create second node. So if you remove createNode function then .query function create a node and also persistent in database as well as in nodejs.